# Menu control CSS breaks when inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a menu control inside of an updatepanel. When I hover over a selected item, and then move back off of it, the css class gets set to staticSubMenuItem instead of staticSubMenuItemSelected. Is there a fix for this?

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:Menu ID="SubMenu" runat="server" SkinID="subMenu" OnMenuItemClick="SubMenu_Click"
                CssClass="floatRight" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItem" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemSelected"
                StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemSelected">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 1" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2" Value="1" />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemSelected"
StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemSelected"

If you have a different CssClass set for Selected and Hover, the problem is fixed. Create a "Hover" css class and change the above to:

StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemSelected"
StaticHoverStyle-CssClass="staticSubMenuItemHover"